# Change variable while dismissing modal controller

Tags: swift, xcode

EDIT: I have decided to change the way my app works, so this problem is solved. Thanks to everyone who helped!

I have a modal controller where when I press a button it dismisses the view. What I want to do is change a variable in another view controller when I dismiss it, is that possible? Or, if this doesn't work, is there a way for me to access the changed variable of another swift file? I will add my code below:

```
class PopupViewController: UIViewController {
    var event = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

    @IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func event910(_ sender: Any) {
        event = "storyTime"
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc = segue.destination as! ViewController
        vc.event = event
    }
}
```

I want to pass the changed variable "event" to another view controller, how can I do this?

Comment: How is  *another view controller* related to `PopupViewController` with regard to the view hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegate View Controller is as follows. : -

it is the place where you will send the data to the next swift file

```
protocol myprotocol {

func anyfunction(_ param1:String)
}


struct mystruct1 {

var delegate:myprotocol?
// where you want tot start the delegate / send the data to the next file
func anymethod(){
    delegate.anyfunction(sendTheDataYouWant)
}
}
// it is here you will receive the data 

class anyclass:UIViewController ,myprotocol {
let class1 = mystruct1() 
  override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        class1.delegate  = self
     
  
    }

func anyfunction(param1:String){
// here Save the data you want 
// because this function will be triggered as delegate will be called
}


}
```

ps:- I reccomend you to read  https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Protocols.html
& apple docs

Comment: Since I am dismissing the modal controller, there is no segue, right? I would do that, but dismissal is not a segue.

Comment: You can use Delegate View Pattern in which you can transfer data before dismissing Your model

Comment: Could you explain how i could do that?

Comment: added new answer hope this helps You  :)

Comment: In delegate.anyFunction(sendTheDataYouWant), how can i reference my variable from my class?

Comment: as said the anyfunc will have prameters pass the parameters from your class

Comment: I am still a bit more confused, could you add on to my current code that I have added to my question?